# Doctrine2 updateSchema collides with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, doctrine, foreign-keys

`updateSchema` runs well with an empty database, but the second time I get the following MySQL error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of
    './mydatabase/#sql-7f5_2b' to
    './mydatabase/mytable' (errno: 150)
```

According to a quick search this error happens on foreign constraint violations. The right approach would be for doctrine to disable foreign key checks when `ALTER`ing a table.

Is there something I can do about this (besides patching Dcotrine)?

Further more I'm specifying:

```
'engine' => 'myisam',
```

... in the `connectionOptions`, but it gets ignored.

---

**Edit:**

When I remove foreign keys from other tables containing reference to `mytable` the error won't happen (it will happen with the next table which is still referenced by FKs but not with `mytable`).

Comment: Would you mind posting the modeling behind the schema you're trying to update?

Comment: @fd8s0 I can't share the ones I used but I will try to create a demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Doctrine doesn't handle this situation completely right.

You should disable the constraints by yourself and let Doctrine to recreate them.
To disable constraints, connect to MySQL and type:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mytable;
```

It will give you the SQL needed to create the table, where you'll see the constraint creation directive. Suppose the constraint is called 'mytable_fk', then you need to issue the command:

```
    ALTER TABLE mytable 
DROP CONSTRAINT mytable_fk;
```

The next time you run updateSchema, Doctrine will detect the missing restriction and will recreate it if needed.